# jQuery Animation Interpolation Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a horizontal slideshow. See it here

http://racheljustice.spencerdupre.org/childrens.html#

The images are all lined up, evenly spaced on a tray div.  jQuery animates that div's margin-left value by -100% every time the next nav button is clicked.

My issue is with the transition from the twelfth image to the thirteenth. The interpolation is all off. I'd obviously like it to just slide gently to the left like all the others do. After some testing it seems jQuery simply doesn't like the margin-left value of 1200.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong, unfortunately you were bit by bug [#7193](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7193), if you make your animation slow (i.e. replace "1000" with "10000") you will notice it goes back to the first photo (0) and then it scrolls all the way to -1300%. There are a couple of patches mentioned within the ticket, but I have no idea if they work (my guess is that this has not been patched because they have lots of backward compability stuff to take care of, so if you go ahead and put "return r", you should be ok.

Comment: No problem! It's good etiquette on StackOverflow to click on the checkmark if the answer solved your problem, because it lets other users know this is solved :)